# Commands on the Windows terminal doesn't work

Tags: windows, terminal

I have a problem with my terminal on windows 7, it doesn't work with the commands `ls` or `make`  and I don't know where my problem come from.

Comment: What terminal are you using? As Wes mentioned below unless you are using a terminal emulator in Windows Command Prompt you want to use Dir for ls and mkdir for make...

Answer (score 2):

`ls` and `make` are not Windows commands.  You're confusing the Windows command prompt with a Linux terminal shell.

For `ls`, you can use the DIR command.  It's significantly different than `ls` though.  As for `make`, Windows does not have a built-in compiler the way Linux/Unix does.